# Hook all command output within bash

Tags: bash, terminal, hook

Just for fun I want to pipe all output text in a terminal to `espeak`. For example, after this is set up I should be able to type `echo hi` and hear "hi" spoken, or `ls` and hear my directory contents listed.

The only promising method to capture output I've found so far is from here: http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/bash-redirections-using-exec

This is what I have so far:

```
npipe=/tmp/$$.tmp
mknod $npipe p
tee /dev/tty <$npipe | espeak &
espeakpid=$!
exec 1>&-
exec 1>$npipe
trap "rm -f $npipe; kill $espeakpid" EXIT
```

It works (also printing a bunch of "Done" jobs), but creating the named pipe, removing with trap and printing the output with `tee` all just seems a bit messy. Is there a simpler way?

Comment: Only  to hook all commands output is easy with `exec > >(tee bash.log)`. But correctly handle terminations, IPC (without ever filling file) etc.. the above is a correct way.

Comment: @jm666 thanks, is there a way to redirect with a pipe rather than to a file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is one way:

```
exec > >(exec tee >(exec xargs -n 1 -d '\n' espeak -- &>/dev/null))
```

If you want to be able to restore back to original output stream:

```
exec 3>&1  ## Store original stdout to fd 3.
exec 4> >(exec tee >(exec xargs -n 1 -d '\n' espeak -- &>/dev/null))  ## Open "espeak" as fd 4.
exec >&4  ## Redirect stdout to "espeak".
exec >&3  ## Redirect back to normal.
```

- I use `xargs -n 1` because `espeak` doesn't do anything until EOF is reached so we summon an instance of it per line. This can be customized of course, but there's your answer. And of course a `while read` loop can also be an option for this.
- I also use `exec`'s in process substitution to make sure we get rid of unnecessary subshells.

Comment: Could you explain what this does and how? Does it redirect all terminal output?

Comment: @Llamageddon You need to have a basic understanding of [file descriptors](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_descriptor). I suggest you look up some wikis or howtos about it. The stdin (0), stdout (1) and stderr (2) are by default linked to the terminal but can be redirected to other files and streams. Bash itself is a process and the `exec` command can be used to manipulate Bash's open file descriptors. Child processes opened by bash one-time inherits Bash's file descriptors' state. Also read the Bash manual and look for the documentation of the `exec` command.

Comment: @Llamageddon Also look for "Process Substitution" in Bash's manual.

Comment: I'm aware of file descriptors, I just had no idea you could redirect them for a running shell with exec. Can I do this inside hooks/traps in either bash or zsh in order to redirect only the process output and not the prompt?

Comment: @Llamageddon You mean make a default child process output? Maybe you can use the [DEBUG trap and the PROMPT_COMMAND variable](https://jichu4n.com/posts/debug-trap-and-prompt_command-in-bash/), but I don't think that's a good idea.

Comment: Why not a good idea? Because of programs that differentiate stdout from other descriptors?

Comment: @Llamageddon Haven't really loooked into it, but too hacky for me.

Comment: Is there any other approach, though? I want to configure my ZSH to store all output, and to wrap output of some processes up, to colorize it and/or to only display the first and last few lines with a `[...]` in the middle.

Comment: @Llamageddon I suggest creating a new question post so knowledgeable people interested in implementing that behavior can help you. I only suggested DEBUG and PROMPT_COMMAND but I have no idea if they can really work. I'm also not interested in studying a script to make what you desire work... not to mention the solution you're seeking turns out to be for Zsh, and not Bash.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like it's way easier than that - I just tested this and it works:

```
$ echo "these are not the droids you are looking for" | espeak --stdin
```

The `--stdin` flag is the key.  From `espeak`'s man page:

> ```
>    --stdin
>           Read text input from stdin instead of a file
> ```

And if what you want to hear is a very long output, I guess you can use `xargs` if you run into *Argument list too long* errors...

Comment: I'm quite comfortable piping to espeak (as is already in my example). The problem I'm having it capturing the output from any command within the bash shell, also without interfering with the output itself. For example `bash | tee /dev/tty | espeak`, unfortunately this creates a new shell which I'd prefer to avoid.