# Invisible terminal output is breaking a script

Tags: linux, bash, special-characters

This is a continuation from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24843014/hook-all-command-output-within-bash) where I catpure all output to a terminal. This script ran fine on my machine, but on another I was hearing extra stuff when piping to `espeak` and not when writing to a file or printing it. This was a bit of a pain to debug but with a little trial and error, I think narrowed it down to `~/.bashrc`->`/etc/bashrc`->`/etc/profiles.d/vte.sh` doing something which I think is setting `PROMPT_COMMAND="__vte_prompt_command"`. At least I thought it was but `PROMPT_COMMAND=` doesn't fix after sourcing `vte.sh`.

At any rate, it appears some special characters are printed to change the window title (`printf "\033]0;%s@%s:%s\007%s"...` maybe?). These characters don't appear when writing to a file or as output in the terminal, but do when piping to apps such as `espeak`.

My first question is, **how should I have detected the existence of these special characters?** (I only found `vte` by trial and error, which seems pretty slow)

```
while read line
do
    espeak "$line" #can hear extra stuff
    echo "GOT: [$line]" #only expected output printed
done <input_pipe
```

My next question is, **how can I ignore any invisible/special output in my loop?** (and get only the caracters I would ultimately see in the terminal)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try removing those characters with special parameter expansion:

```
line=${line//stringtodelete}
line=${line//[charstodelete]}
```

Try to run `echo -n "$line" | hexdump -C` to see the hex values of those characters.

Then you can do something like

```
$'\x01\x02abc'
```

Notes:

- Bash replaces `\[` and  `\]` in `PS1` with `$'\x01'` and `$'\x02'` respectively but I'm not sure if they're sent on actual output.
- `$'\x##'` is hex form and `$'\000'` is oct form.

Comment: Just stripping characters isn't quite robust enough. Removing whole "control" sequences [using regex](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/14684/removing-control-chars-including-console-codes-colours-from-script-output) seems to do a pretty good job but I'm still left feeling there should be a better way. Thanks for the info! Especially `hexdump`.